Cypress - RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString
I'm using cypress version 13.9.0 and I get RangeError: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString on cy.reload().
Any ideas how to overcome it?
  waitForUpdate(employeeId, employeeName, employeeEmail) {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('activeToken')).token.token;
    cy.clock(new Date()); // Start a clock to control the timeout

    const checkStatus = () => {
      cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: Cypress.config().baseUrl + `api/v1/employee/${employeeId}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
        const { name, email } = response.body;

        if (name === employeeName && email === employeeEmail) {
          // Task found and status is as expected
          cy.log("Employees' data updated");
          cy.reload();
        } else if (new Date().getTime() - startTime < 900000) {
          // Retry for a maximum of 15 minutes (900000 milliseconds)
          // eslint-disable-next-line cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting
          cy.wait(15000); // Wait for 15 seconds
          checkStatus(); // Retry the request
        } else {
          // Timeout exceeded, fail the test
          cy.log('Employees data is not updated within 15 minutes.');
          expect(false).to.equal(true); // Fail the test
        }
      });
    };

    const startTime = new Date().getTime();
    checkStatus(); // Start checking the status
  }

I am getting the following error:
RangeError: The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

  > Invalid time value

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the `uncaught:exception` event.
    at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
    at q.end (main.a1444de99b433347.js:1:216062)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.a1444de99b433347.js:1:62383)
    at I.invokeTask (polyfills.2ba72d64643256ee.js:1:7246)
    at B.runTask (polyfills.2ba72d64643256ee.js:1:2614)
    at b.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.2ba72d64643256ee.js:1:8300)
    at j (polyfills.2ba72d64643256ee.js:1:20943)
    at x (polyfills.2ba72d64643256ee.js:1:21349)
    at HTMLDocument.J (polyfills.2ba72d64643256ee.js:1:21513)


Tried with different types of page reload, used javascript win.reload.
Tried with cy.clock manipulation.
Error is persisting.
EDIT: It is fixed by removing cy.clock() as it causes some kind of interfernce with time-based operations in the application
Instead of cy.clock(), I am simply using const startTime = new Date().getTime() and everything else stays the same.

I observed that behavior too, when I try to manipulate the clock to check session timeouts. My guess, that the auth service (keycloak) is detecting the manipulated local time when it differs from the auth token time. So I just thought, in this case it's not possible to do it.

There doesn't seem to be anything in your waitForUpdate method that can cause that, it's just performing a cy.request() which should not have an impact on the loaded page.
You can try moving the cy.reload() outside of the function, in which case you probably would use Custom Commands to avoid synchronicity problems.
Something like this:
Cypress.Commands.add('waitForUpdate', (employeeId, employeeName, employeeEmail) => {

  // code for recursive polling, without the cy.reload()

})

it('run the test', () => {
  cy.waitForUpdate(employeeId, employeeName, employeeEmail) 
    .then(() => cy.reload() )

